# How to get filtered results from clarity datagrid?

Tags: angular, typescript, vmware-clarity

For my project at work I am using Angular for the frontend with Clarity Design. I have set up the datagrid with filtering. Now I want to get the list of filtered results to use inside another component. So I haven't found anything yet that makes it possible. That lead me to the question is it possible to get the filtered results out of the datagrid?

Here is a very simple datagrid example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clr-dg-filter-result

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently an API to get the filtered list out, but currently the only support we have for is simple string filtering. You can get the active filters and apply the logic yourself to figure out what the list shows, example here https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/string-filtering.